# Getting NullPointerException with AlphabetIndexer

Tags: android

```
I'm having a hard time here with AlphabetIndexer here. I'm trying to use it to produce sectioned listview:

private static final String sAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";

private AlphabetIndexer mIndexer;

    public ContactAlphabetizedAdapter(Context context, int layout,
            Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);

        mIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(cursor, cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME), sAlphabet);
```

On my device I app crashes and the problem is:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(5188): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.widget.AlphabetIndexer.compare(AlphabetIndexer.java:128)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.widget.AlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(AlphabetIndexer.java:265)
```

That's something to AlphabetIndexer internals, how do I fix this?

Comment: check what is at AlphabetIndexer.java:128 ?

Comment: That's AlphabetIndexer's source.

Comment: in that alphatic source what does line number 128 contain

Comment: That's android class, so I won't be able to modify it anyway.

Comment: That's not the point. It might help to see what alphabetindexer is refering to at that point. That way you'll know where your problem is.

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224233/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter-managed-by-loadermanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably post more of your code to confirm this, but I'm guessing you cursos has changed, *or for some other reason cursor[columnIndex] returns null*, by the time `getSectionForPosition` is evaluated.

According to [this outstanding issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6061), this situation will trigger a very similar NPE to what you are experiencing

Again, the *real* problem is somewhere in the code that you didn't post. The Alphabetindexer is just not handling that situation all too well.